# How to find all the duplicates of an element in a 2d array in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv, duplicates

I have the array down here (the data from a csv file)

```
Array ( [0] => 56 [1] => reza [2] => red [3] => 99 [4] => 23 [5] => rp@gamik [6] => 25 greenview [7] => park )

Array ( [0] => 99 [1] => harry [2] => green [3] => 100 [4] => 34 [5] => ee@gmail [6] => 11 hanlen park [7] => linda ) 

Array ( [0] => 77 [1] => john [2] => blue [3] => 101 [4] => 44 [5] => rrrrr@gmail [6] => 22 yonge [7] => harry ) 

Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => paul [2] => white [3] => 102 [4] => 22 [5] => pof@gmail [6] => 42 hw7 [7] => Palmer ) 

Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => nate [2] => pink [3] => 103 [4] => 99 [5] => jjhf@gmail [6] => 45 hendon [7] => harry )
```

I want the program to iterate over each element and find the address of the duplicates (row and column)

I was able to do it with a specific element name like here

```
function findData($fileName , $tb){

        $handle = fopen($fileName , "r");
        

        $rows = [];
        $flag = 0; // to find the rows

        while ($csvcontent = fgetcsv($handle)){


            for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($csvcontent) ; $i++) {
                if ($csvcontent[$i] == 'harry') {

                    echo $i;
                    array_push($rows , $flag);

                }
            }

            $flag++;

        }

         print_r($rows);

    }
```

which gives me the output `177Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 )` being the columns and the rows of the duplicates.

Now I want it to check every element of the array for duplicates and find me their rows and columns.

Comment: can you show arrows like `  arr = [1,11,22] `

Comment: @JagadishLenka 
Ah sure It's a 2d array like [ [56 , 'reza' , 'red' , 99 , 23] , [ 99 , 'harry' , green , 100 , 34] , ... ]

Comment: can you replace your all arrays frm `Array ( [0] => 56 [1] => reza [2] => red [3] => 99 [4] => 23 [5] => rp@gamik [6] => 25 greenview [7] => park )` to `arr1 = [56 ,reza56 , 'reza' , 'red' , 99 , 23]` mean to proper coded arrray format in your question.